# Как передвинуть img

Tags: html, css

Как передвинуть ***img***

Как я не пытался не ***padding***, не ***margin***, не ***right left*** не работали

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.apps {
  left: 40%;
  top: 25%;
  position: fixed;
}

.toppanel {
  right: 1%;
  top: 3%;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.toppanel a {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.toppanel :hover {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="toppanel">
  <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/56/56844.svg" alt="aaa" width="20" height="20" class="apps">
  <a>Gmail</a>
  <a>Images</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.toppanel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.toppanel > * + * {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.toppanel:hover {
  color: #a8a8a8;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="toppanel">
  <a>Gmail</a>
  <a>Images</a>
  <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/56/56844.svg" alt="aaa" width="20" height="20" class="apps">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.apps {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}
.apps:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px red);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

такие простые задачи решают  `grid` или `flex`

```css
.toppanel {
  right: 1%;
  top: 3%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-right: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

img {
  margin: 0 0 0 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toppanel">
  <a>Gmail</a>
  <a>Images</a>
  <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/56/56844.svg" alt="aaa" width="20" height="20" class="apps">
</div>
```